# How to generate a series with recurrence relation?

Tags: equation-solving, difference-equations

I am a beginner in Mathematica and stuck on a problem.
I want to generate a series using a recurrence relation, however, I am facing the problem while feeding previous values.

```
b[0] == 1
b[n+1] == b[n] + n/x^n
```

I need the following result,

```
b[0] + b[1] + b[2] + b[3] .....
```

Comment: Did you try anything? You'll get more answers if you show some effort from your side. Also, try to search (this site, google, and the documentation center) for a solution to your problem. Very rarely are you the first to face a particular issue ;)

Comment: see [RecurrenceTable](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RecurrenceTable.html)

Comment: If you're looking for the infinite sum, it's divergent, at least for $x > 0$.  Proof:  $b_{n} > b_{n-1}$ by the recurrence relation, which means $b_n > b_0 = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: (I'm pretty sure that the sum of the series diverges for $x < 0$ as well, but I haven't been able to find a similarly simple proof.)

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

By [advice from @kglr in comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174406/how-to-generate-a-series-with-recurrence-relation#comment457864_174406):

```
Total@RecurrenceTable[{b[n + 1] == b[n] + n/x^n, b[0] == 1}, b, {n, 0, 10}]
```

> $\frac{9}{x^9}+\frac{16}{x^8}+\frac{21}{x^7}+\frac{24}{x^6}+\frac{25}{x^5}+\frac{24}{x^4}+\frac{21}{x^3}+\frac{16}{x^2}+\frac{9}{x}+11$

Another way:

```
sol = RSolve[{b[n + 1] == b[n] + n/x^n, b[0] == 1}, b[n], n]
```

> $\left\{\left\{b(n)\to \frac{x^{-n} \left(-x+n x-n x^2+x^n-x^{1+n}+x^{2+n}\right)}{(-1+x)^2}\right\}\right\}$

```
Total@Table[b[n] /. sol[[1]], {n, 0, 10}] // FullSimplify // Expand
```

give the same answer what is above.